# How to count agents and save the number to a variable

Tags: count, anylogic

I would like to count the number of agents that exits the Sink and save that number continuously to my variable "Loads" while i run the simulation.

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfZ1x.jpg

Anylogic suggets the following.. but i can't seem to get it right. 
long count() - returns the number of agents exited via this Sink block.

hope some of you can help me out

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy... you don't even need a variable since `sink.count()` has the information you need always.

But if you insist in creating one, You can also create a variable called counter of type int and on the sink action just use `counter++;`